# How to make an the Organisation Structure by taking the details through Visio diagrammatic representation

Tags: visio, organization-profile

I want to build an Organization Structure/chart in SharePoint using the Visio diagram that means I want to pull the data/fields from Visio and then it would make an Org chart in SharePoint. Please suggest

Comment: How do you want your org chart display in SharePoint , will it be a webpart or silverlight,etc. Or will u just consumer Visio services to read the visio file ?

Comment: Thanks.. Arko for the reply. I want to consume Visio Services to read the Visio file. Do not want to consume Web part or Silverlight. Could you please provide me the steps. We have a highly customized mySite.